# Facebook-Like Notification System (Globe Icon)

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification system like the one in Facebook. I explain my exact aim of this notification system at the end of this post.

The following code should show all notifications about posts/ratings/etc. except my posts of course. Also it should show all notifications where I'm the creator of a content (`n.creator_id`). But the result is empty:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `notification_read` WHERE `is_read`='0' AND `uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."') AS count,
n.`id`,n.`site`,n.`site_id`,n.`creator_uid`,n.`type`,
nu.`id` AS nuid,nu.`uid` AS nu_uid,nu.`date`,
u.`gender`

FROM `notification` AS n
LEFT JOIN `notification_user` AS nu ON nu.`nid` = n.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u ON u.`id` = nu.`uid` 
WHERE 
    ( 
    nu.`uid` != '".$_SESSION['uid']."'
    AND
    n.`creator_uid` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'
    )
GROUP BY n.`id` 
ORDER BY nu.`date` DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Table structures are:

`notification`: id, site_id, creator_uid, site, type

`notification_user`: id, nid, uid, date

`notification_read`: id, nuid, uid, is_read

Further explanation: I need to LEFT JOIN `users` because I need the gender to say "X liked his/her comment". The COUNT shows the amount of notifications I want to display on that globe icon.

Also I couldn't think of a better table structure for my needs thinking of that what I want to do. But I'm open for suggestions, if there are better ways or better table structures or anything else I could improve.

My aim is to display notifications for:

- content I've created (img uploaded, comments, ratings, etc)
- content of others I've commented, rated, etc.
- if I gained credits
- if someone used my referal link to sign up on the website

So pretty much the basic social network things. Thank you in advance for suggestions about that structure or/and to answers to my question why my SELECT statement shows an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got into the same situations for this and I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887602/facebook-like-notifications-tracking-db-design#answer-1892311)

so maybe you can get an idea on that post.