# mysql table notification structure like facebook

Tags: mysql

did this right way for make table notification some thing like facebook

table notification

```
id , status_id , comment_id , reply_id
1      1           null         null
2      null         3           null
```

now table for save on it who make the notification some thing like user1 and user2 and user4 comment on your post

notification_maker

```
id , notification_id , user_id ,    info
1       1                66         comment on your post
1       1                77         comment on your post
```

i dont know maby some thing like this andy ideas about how to make tables for notification like facebook

Comment: What is this _like facebook_ you're talking about?

Comment: iam talk about notification in facebook if someone comment on your post he give you notification like user1 comment on your post and if second user comment will give you notification like user1 and user2 comment on your post also when share and like and react

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook like notifications tracking (DB Design)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887602/facebook-like-notifications-tracking-db-design)